# Unable to print out the desired output

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, linked-list

So I am creating a program that reads customer details and order details from two different files. I created methods to read the file, store the data in the object of customers and then add the object of customers into linkedlist.. Now when I try doing the same for order file, I am getting the wrong output. so in the code shown below, I am trying to check if the customer name entered in order file matches the name stored in customer linkedlist.. So say I have two rows in the order.txt file:

```
Ord101 true James
Ord102 false Jim
```

with what I have done, I get the following output:

```
Ord102 false Jim
Ord102 false Jim
```

instead of getting the correct output which would be:

```
Ord101 true James
Ord102 false Jim
```

because both, James and Jim are names present in Customer file and linkedlist. So here is my code for reading order file:

```
public void readFileOrder() {
Scanner y;
String b,c,d;
LinkedList<Customers> list=new LinkedList<Customers>(); //another method was already created to add data inside list and its working so list contains data

LinkedList<order> list1=new LinkedList<order>();
Boolean isOpen;
order Order1=new order();
while(y.hasNext())
{

b=y.next();
isOpen=y.nextBoolean();
d=y.next();
System.out.println(list);
Customers customers1=new Customers();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)    //this is where i'm checking if the customer name in the order file matches the value in list
{
 if(list.get(i).getName().equals(d))
  {
   customers1=list.get(i);
   Order1.setCustomer(customers1);
Order1.setName(b);
Order1.setIsOpen(isOpen);
list1.add(Order1);
   }
}


}

for(int j=0;j<list1.size();j++)
{
System.out.println(list1.get(j).getCustomer()+" and "+list1.get(j).getName()+" and "+list1.get(j).getIsOpen());
}
}
```

just in case, provided below are Customer and order class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Customers {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customers [Name=" + Name + ", age=" + age + ", email=" + email + ", Address=" + Address + "]";
    }
    String Name;
    int age;
    String email;
    String Address;
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }
    public void removeCustomer(String name2, LinkedList<Customers> list) {
        for(int k=0;k<list.size();k++)
        {
            if(list.get(k).getName().equals(name2))
            {
                list.remove(list.get(k));
            }
        }

    }


}
```

order class:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class order{
String name;
Boolean isOpen;
Customers customer;
String cusName;
public order() {
    super();

}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public order(Customers customer) {
    super();
    this.customer = customer;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Boolean getIsOpen() {
    return isOpen;
}
public void setIsOpen(Boolean isOpen) {
    this.isOpen = isOpen;
}
public String getCustomer() {
    return customer.getName();
}
public void setCustomer(Customers customer) {
    this.customer=customer;
    this.cusName=customer.getName();
}
}
```

Comment: Odd that the class representing a single customer is called `Customers`. Unless I missed something.

Comment: You are iterating over the entire customer list multiple times, once for each order in the file. That isn't a big problem especially if your file is small, but have you considered using a `HashMap` for instant lookup by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding references to *the same* `order` to the list over and over again, each time overwriting the attributes set in the previous iteration of the loop. Instead, create a `new order` *inside* the loop.

In other words, change this:

```
order Order1=new order();
while(y.hasNext()) {
```

to this:

```
while(y.hasNext()) {
    order Order1=new order();
```